# Why it is not correct to use "aufwinden" in this context

Tags: semantics

One of my colleagues said that it is not correct to use verb **aufwinden** in the following context:

> Die Holzstücke waren aufgewunden um ein Holzbündel

On the other side this usage is completely correct:

> Man soll ein Kabel auf eine Rolle aufwinden, um es einfacher zu transportieren

Why first example is not correct? Is it because of article **um** / **auf** or it is something other? Unfortunately de.thefreedictionary.com doesn't have too much information about it as well as linguee.com / Duden

Comment: "Aufwinden" translates to "wind", "coil" or "reel", but is only used seldom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das erste Beispiel müsste

> Die Holzstücke waren zu einem Holzbündel aufgewunden.

heißen, da die Holzstücke zu einem Bündel mit einer Schnur zusammengebunden werden. Durch das *um* bedeutet es eher, dass die Holzstücke dazu verwendet werden, das Holzbündel zusammenzuhalten. Die Stücke gehen ja nicht *um das Bündel herum* sondern sind darin enthalten.

*Aufwinden* kann man nur Kabel, Leinen, Seile, Strippen usw. aber keine festen Gegenstände wie Holzbündel. Die kann man höchstens *umwinden*.